# MissingMethodException when using zxing.Monotouch on iOS6

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios6, zxing

I have updated my development system to the new MonoTouch (6.0.1) and now whenever I'm referencing zxing.Monotouch types I get MissingMethodException on the constructor.
`System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'MyClass..ctor'.`
It's been 3 days now...
Anyone got any idea? I'm even willing to give up zxing if that what it takes (even though it's a wonderful library).

*Edit*

When I include zxing.Monotouch in the solution and reference it as a project the problem does not reproduce. If that's a clue I've missed it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that the binary version of `zxing.Monotouch` is trying to access something that does not exists in 6.0.1. That's uncommon as we try to maintain source/binary compatibility **unless** the code is really broken (e.g. it would cause a crash anyway). I cannot be more precise without more data (e.g. a full build log).

If you include `zxing.Monotouch` as a reference then it will be **rebuilt**. If it works then it really looks like source compatibility was preserved (but not binary compatibility).

Whenever you have the source code available I encourage you to use .csproj (not .dll) references. Is has a few advantages, including the source/binary compatibility (above) and the fact that it makes things easier to debug from your project.

Comment: I normally prefer DLL reference over project reference because I don't want to clog my repositories but at least in this case it solved the problem. 
It is still a mystery to me since I rebuilt the zxing.Monotouch library using 6.0.1 and it didn't solve the problem.